# Cannot change only one panel value of datepicker

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I'm using datepicker with daterage option.

```
   <el-date-picker
        v-model="offerPeriod"
        type="daterange"  
        :format="'yyyy-MM-dd'"
        placeholder="Datetime picker here" 
      ></el-date-picker>
```

[image: ( &]

I want when change one range, the other range is still checked. 
[image]

Any help please ?

Comment: can you share your code, and what do you mean by change one range ?

Comment: I mean when I want to change  one value, I'm obliged to reselect the other one.  As the image shows, i want to change the  value of the first range( 22May2020), the second range (which is 18June 2020) is lost.

Comment: Very short, this is not possible with element-ui. It also doesn't really fit in the design of the component, what if you only want to change to end date? Basically this means they have to split the start an and date into 2 fields.

Comment: @dreijntjens that's the problem :\. I didn't find anyway to split the two ranges.

Comment: What I tried to say was that you can't use the component for this, You have to use to seperate (non range) datepickers instead, or maybe there is some third party library for this but then the style is different